# what is the correct way to set up ssr with nextjs at layout

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with ssr nextjs.

At root layout I have a children using getServerSideProps and does all i want with ssr, which is good. but when I do the same thing, at `<Header/>`, then got an error:**You’re importing a class component. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.**

layout.js

```
  export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Header/>
        {children}
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

ssrpage.js (both children and header using the same structure)

```
  export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // Fetch data 
     }
    class ReactCategory extends Component {
     //the rest of program
    }
```

I could get away with the error by using "use client" and place it on the top of the file, but then will skip getServerSideProps and render client side, which is not what i want.
Using a functional component is not an option as setstate will not be available and useState is not allowed.

The only option is put the header at every children page but this is kind of silly.

so my question is, **how to ssr header where i can use getServerSideProps and able to use setstate or useState**?